# Windows 8 Black Screen of Death On Boot After Update (Mac Pro, Boot Camp). What are the recovery options?

Tags: windows, windows-8, system-restore

After installing an update (well, after the system auto-updated itself one day upon rebooting), a windows logo followed by a black screen of death (with no cursor) greets me upon bootup.

This BSOD is seen whether the system is booted from BootCamp on its own hard disk (which is, incidentally, factory new), or from Parallels. Exact same situation.

I booted into safe mode with networking, and also with low resolution, and both still yield a black screen.

I started the system with its DVD and ran the problem detection automation that's available on the Win8 Pro DVD ("detect and automatically repair problems") and no problems were found.

I can boot up via that DVD and get myself a "command.com" prompt, where all the directories, etc. appear intact. What recovery procedures could I use in order to avoid losing my files; either through the command.com command line or through a more clever method? Note: 'Refresh Your PC" would not be an answer to this question, since that will cause all my data not part of the App Store world to be deleted.

Comment: You need to backup your data.  This sounds like a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is what I did.

Restart your pc then boot from cd/dvd, press "custom install" (if you want to fresh install that is) let it load the files and all that then when it asks install updates automatically say no to that, its not recommended by Microsoft but you still have the option.

Afterwards you will get the personalisation screen, set up your email, username and password after that you should/will be in Windows, this worked for me finally after months of BSOD'S this problem is most likely to do with a certain update that it obtains from the Microsoft update.